# "Related" questions section is dancing

Tags: bug, user-interface

I just noticed the `hover` behaviour of Related Questions section. Below there's another section "Hot Network Questions" that is performing well on `hover`. Is that a bug or *is it a feature*?

[Here's the gif.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovDUg.gif)

**Edit for clarification**:
When hovering elements from the *Related* [questions] section, a 1px border is added at the bottom of the element that is being hovered. The 1px border doesn't exist in the default state of the element which causes elements below the one that's being hovered to be pushed with 1px .

**Browser**: Chrome, Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)

**OS**: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

This problem is reproducible in 99% of the browser, I believe. Since it's expected behaviour when you're adding border at the bottom of an element, that doesn't exist, without the element being hovered.

**Edit**: The problem is obviously fixed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what the problem is, what browser you are using and on what OS. Then, if this is a bug, also add the [bug] tag.

Comment: @terdon It looks as if the line spacing alters on mouseover, or it's due to the thin line that gets inserted between the links, and that makes them "dance". I see this too in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, so do I, but if the devs are to look at this it would be helpful if the problem were explicitly described and the software needed to reproduce it mentioned.

Comment: @terdon There I edited my question and *explained* what is happening...